# Create a function to send mail from a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've several divs with a email icon.

```
<div class="icon-send-mail" id="test1@email.com"></div>
<div class="icon-send-mail" id="test2@email.com"></div>
<div class="icon-send-mail" id="test3@email.com"></div>
```

I want to send an email when the user clicks on that icon.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $('.icon-send-mail').click(function(email) {
      var mailto_link = 'mailto:'+email;
      var win = window.open(mailto_link,'emailWindow');
    });
});
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You're using an ID selector `#` instead of a class selector `.`.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4

Comment: don't edit your code.  As @CrazyTrain mentioned that may be the cause of error. have you check it?

Comment: So you defined an `email` parameter to the function, and you were hoping it would magically reference the `ID` attribute's value?

Comment: That's working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/MmbZZ/ (since you edited the code after CrazyTrain's comment)

Comment: You're right @JeffNoel.  I agree.

Comment: @user1671639  Yes I've checked it. Maybe you've should also checked.

Comment: @DKALT I gave an alternate solution, considering you might want to optimize your code. You were also passing the `event` object (named `email` for some obscure reasons). Check the performance benchmark I added too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $('.icon-send-mail').on('click', function(e) {
        var mailto_link = 'mailto:' + $(this).attr('id');
        var win = window.open(mailto_link, 'emailWindow');
    });
});
```

Comment: `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: @jterry It's always better to use pure javascript when you can, especially for a few characters where it can make a huge performance difference for not so much of code.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the first line within your function:

```
/* You were passing the event object! */
var mailto_link = 'mailto:'+this.id;
```

---

### [Custom JQuery vs JavaScript performance benchmark](http://jsperf.com/jquery-click-event-vs-pure-javascript)

### JavaScript/JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.icon-send-mail').click(function(event) {
      var mailto_link = 'mailto:'+this.id;
      var win = window.open(mailto_link,'emailWindow');
    });
});
```

---

### Pure Javascript

```
window.onload = function () {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-send-mail');
    for (var i in elems) {
        if (elems[i].nodeType == 1) elems[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            var mailto_link = 'mailto:' + this.id;
            var win = window.open(mailto_link, 'emailWindow');
        });
    }
};
```

### Bonus CSS

```
.icon-send-mail {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/MmbZZ/2/)

Answer (score 3):

The input to a click handler is an event object.  Within that event object you can get the element that was clicked on and therefore it's id, which in your case holds the email address

```
$('.icon-send-mail').click(function(event) {
  var mailto_link = 'mailto:'+event.target.id;
  var win = window.open(mailto_link,'emailWindow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your this line:

```
var mailto_link = 'mailto:'+email;
```

with the following line:

```
var mailto_link = 'mailto:'+($(this).attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Call below code inside you Click event

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Mail.aspx/SendMail",
       cache: false,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: "{ 'body':'"  + messageBody + "'," +
                 "'to': '" + msgTo + "'," +
                 "'from': '" + msgFrom + "'," +
                 "'subject': " + msgSubject + "'" +
             "}",
       dataType: "json",
       complete: function (transport) {  if (transport.status == 200) $("#formcontainer").html("Success"); else alert("Please try again later"); }
   });
```

and write the mailing code on Code behind

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mydomain.com");
            mail.To.Add("u@urdomain.com");
            mail.Subject = filename;
            mail.Body = "Report";
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(filename);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("me", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```