# How to email dynamic contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I'm looking for a way to email the contents of a dynamically added div. The idea is that of a newsletter consisting of a list of titles and texts displayed one by one when a user clicks on a title.

When a text is displayed, the user can click a "Send email" button, and then his or her mail client opens with a new email where the text (the contents of the div in question) is loaded as the email body (ideally, the title should also be displayed in the email title field). When clicking on another title and another text is displayed, it is of course this one that's to be sent to the email.

My JavaScript knowledge is limited, and I'm even newer to jQuery. My draft relies on this important solution: [How to display a second JSON element in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748328/how-to-display-a-second-json-element-in-javascript), but is, I think, also closely related to [Create a function to send mail from a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971580/create-a-function-to-send-mail-from-a-div). It's important that the solution is a lightweight, JavaScript only one - server side scripting is not an option here.

I'd be most grateful for a demonstration, JavaScript or jQuery, how to solve this (I suppose it's the body=[...] in function snd() that's the problem) and excuse in advance if it's a too naive - or a too deceptively simple - question.

My script looks like this:

```
<body>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var article = [
    {
        "title": "This is title no. 1",
        "text": "Here is the text of the first article"
    },
    {
        "title": "This is title no. 2",
        "text": "Here is the text of the second article"
    },
    {
        "title": "This is title no. 3",
        "text": "Here is the text of the third article"
    }
]

function getData() {
    var html = '';
    for(i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
        html += "<li data-text='" + "'>" + article[i].title.link(article[i].text) + "</li>";
    }
    $('#showData').html('<ul>' + html + '</ul>');
    $('#showData').on('click', 'a', function(e) 
        $('#showData .text').remove(); 
        $(this).after('<div class="text">' + $(this).attr('href') + '<p><button onclick="snd(); return false">Send email</button></div>');
        e.preventDefault();            
    });

}
function snd() {
    location.href = "mailto:"+"?subject=Article to read&body="+document.getElementsByClassName('description').innerHTML;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getData();
});

</script>
    <div id="showData"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's a possibility to send E-Mails with JavaScript only, since it's client-side. You need to use PHP for that. There's a simple method in PHP to send E-Mails, check that out.

You can post the Text via AJAX to the PHP-File and let it send it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the code below in your snd() function and somehow incorporate that into your code

```
$("#div-id .steps").each(function(){
 remoteAjax[$(this).attr("id")] = {
  url : "email-content.php", // the url where you're sending data to be mailed
  dataType : 'json',
  beforeSubmit: function(data){$("#data-div").html("data sent to the server: " +  $.param(data))}, //this would be something for debugging your data or use firebug
  success : function(data){
   if(data){ //data is either true or false (returned from email-content.php) 
   simulating successful / failing           
     $("#data").append("    .... data sent successfully. Some type of message on your UI.");
   }else{
     alert("Some type of error that the data wasn't sent successfully and something went wrong.");
   }
```

In the email-content.php file you can form your subject, to, from, message and get real fancy with domain checking to make sure if you can even send the mail to that domain if thats necessary.

You want to create steps in your code to have that level of complexity.